# Why there is 2 primary keys in table (Sentinel framework database)?

Tags: database, laravel, cartalyst-sentinel

i  included SENTINEL framework with implemented Sentinel migration into my LARAVEL project. Lot of things are clear to me but i can't understand why there is 2 primary keys in Role_users table, because i learned that for connection between 2 tables we need primary key and foreign key which is not a case here (role_users table). If someone knows explanation It would mean a lot to me.

my Database Scheme

[image]

Php my admin scheme

[image]

migration_cartalyst_sentinel

```
<?php

/**
 * Part of the Sentinel package.
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * Licensed under the 3-clause BSD License.
 *
 * This source file is subject to the 3-clause BSD License that is
 * bundled with this package in the LICENSE file.
 *
 * @package    Sentinel
 * @version    2.0.17
 * @author     Cartalyst LLC
 * @license    BSD License (3-clause)
 * @copyright  (c) 2011-2017, Cartalyst LLC
 * @link       http://cartalyst.com
 */

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class MigrationCartalystSentinel extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('activations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('code');
            $table->boolean('completed')->default(0);
            $table->timestamp('completed_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });

        Schema::create('persistences', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('code');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->unique('code');
        });

        Schema::create('reminders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('code');
            $table->boolean('completed')->default(0);
            $table->timestamp('completed_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        });

        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('permissions')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->unique('slug');
        });

        Schema::create('role_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->nullableTimestamps();

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->primary(['user_id', 'role_id']);
        });

        Schema::create('throttle', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('ip')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->index('user_id');
        });

        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->text('permissions')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('last_login')->nullable();
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->unique('email');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('activations');
        Schema::drop('persistences');
        Schema::drop('reminders');
        Schema::drop('roles');
        Schema::drop('role_users');
        Schema::drop('throttle');
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

EloquentUser

```
<?php

/**
 * Part of the Sentinel package.
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * Licensed under the 3-clause BSD License.
 *
 * This source file is subject to the 3-clause BSD License that is
 * bundled with this package in the LICENSE file.
 *
 * @package    Sentinel
 * @version    2.0.17
 * @author     Cartalyst LLC
 * @license    BSD License (3-clause)
 * @copyright  (c) 2011-2017, Cartalyst LLC
 * @link       http://cartalyst.com
 */

namespace Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users;

use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Permissions\PermissibleInterface;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Permissions\PermissibleTrait;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Persistences\PersistableInterface;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Roles\RoleableInterface;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Roles\RoleInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EloquentUser extends Model implements RoleableInterface, PermissibleInterface, PersistableInterface, UserInterface
{
    use PermissibleTrait;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'password',
        'last_name',
        'first_name',
        'permissions',
    ];

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected $persistableKey = 'user_id';

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected $persistableRelationship = 'persistences';

    /**
     * Array of login column names.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loginNames = ['email'];

    /**
     * The Eloquent roles model name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $rolesModel = 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Roles\EloquentRole';

    /**
     * The Eloquent persistences model name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $persistencesModel = 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Persistences\EloquentPersistence';

    /**
     * The Eloquent activations model name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $activationsModel = 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Activations\EloquentActivation';

    /**
     * The Eloquent reminders model name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $remindersModel = 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Reminders\EloquentReminder';

    /**
     * The Eloquent throttling model name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $throttlingModel = 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Throttling\EloquentThrottle';

    /**
     * Returns an array of login column names.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLoginNames()
    {
        return $this->loginNames;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles relationship.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(static::$rolesModel, 'role_users', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the persistences relationship.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function persistences()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(static::$persistencesModel, 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the activations relationship.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function activations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(static::$activationsModel, 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the reminders relationship.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function reminders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(static::$remindersModel, 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the throttle relationship.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function throttle()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(static::$throttlingModel, 'user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get mutator for the "permissions" attribute.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $permissions
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPermissionsAttribute($permissions)
    {
        return $permissions ? json_decode($permissions, true) : [];
    }

    /**
     * Set mutator for the "permissions" attribute.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $permissions
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPermissionsAttribute(array $permissions)
    {
        $this->attributes['permissions'] = $permissions ? json_encode($permissions) : '';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function inRole($role)
    {
        if ($role instanceof RoleInterface) {
            $roleId = $role->getRoleId();
        }

        foreach ($this->roles as $instance) {
            if ($role instanceof RoleInterface) {
                if ($instance->getRoleId() === $roleId) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                if ($instance->getRoleId() == $role || $instance->getRoleSlug() == $role) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function generatePersistenceCode()
    {
        return str_random(32);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getPersistableId()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getPersistableKey()
    {
        return $this->persistableKey;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setPersistableKey($key)
    {
        $this->persistableKey = $key;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setPersistableRelationship($persistableRelationship)
    {
        $this->persistableRelationship = $persistableRelationship;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getPersistableRelationship()
    {
        return $this->persistableRelationship;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getUserLogin()
    {
        return $this->getAttribute($this->getUserLoginName());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getUserLoginName()
    {
        return reset($this->loginNames);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getUserPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getRolesModel()
    {
        return static::$rolesModel;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the roles model.
     *
     * @param  string  $rolesModel
     * @return void
     */
    public static function setRolesModel($rolesModel)
    {
        static::$rolesModel = $rolesModel;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the persistences model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getPersistencesModel()
    {
        return static::$persistencesModel;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the persistences model.
     *
     * @param  string  $persistencesModel
     * @return void
     */
    public static function setPersistencesModel($persistencesModel)
    {
        static::$persistencesModel = $persistencesModel;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the activations model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getActivationsModel()
    {
        return static::$activationsModel;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the activations model.
     *
     * @param  string  $activationsModel
     * @return void
     */
    public static function setActivationsModel($activationsModel)
    {
        static::$activationsModel = $activationsModel;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the reminders model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getRemindersModel()
    {
        return static::$remindersModel;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the reminders model.
     *
     * @param  string  $remindersModel
     * @return void
     */
    public static function setRemindersModel($remindersModel)
    {
        static::$remindersModel = $remindersModel;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the throttling model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getThrottlingModel()
    {
        return static::$throttlingModel;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the throttling model.
     *
     * @param  string  $throttlingModel
     * @return void
     */
    public static function setThrottlingModel($throttlingModel)
    {
        static::$throttlingModel = $throttlingModel;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function delete()
    {
        $isSoftDeleted = array_key_exists('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes', class_uses($this));

        if ($this->exists && ! $isSoftDeleted) {
            $this->activations()->delete();
            $this->persistences()->delete();
            $this->reminders()->delete();
            $this->roles()->detach();
            $this->throttle()->delete();
        }

        return parent::delete();
    }

    /**
     * Dynamically pass missing methods to the user.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        $methods = ['hasAccess', 'hasAnyAccess'];

        if (in_array($method, $methods)) {
            $permissions = $this->getPermissionsInstance();

            return call_user_func_array([$permissions, $method], $parameters);
        }

        return parent::__call($method, $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a permissions object.
     *
     * @return \Cartalyst\Sentinel\Permissions\PermissionsInterface
     */
    protected function createPermissions()
    {
        $userPermissions = $this->permissions;

        $rolePermissions = [];

        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
            $rolePermissions[] = $role->permissions;
        }

        return new static::$permissionsClass($userPermissions, $rolePermissions);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a table called `all_users`?

Comment: uhhh my mistake, i mean Role_users table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Role_users` is used as a pivot table in this case; it's the intermediate table in the many-to-many relationship between `Users` and `Roles`. A User can belong to many Roles, and a Role can belong to many Users.

The composite primary key on `Role_users` ensures that no User will have the same Role twice, and vice versa. The primary key is a unique combination of the user_id and role_id.